# Reading back from 1D textures after writing into it with a fragment shader is not working

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to retrive the values that i've writen in a 1D texture in the fragment shader using imageStore() function. I'm generating random points and processing in the fragment shader for generate delaunay triangulation using the circumcircle. When i generate a certain size of points (less than 30), reading from texture works, but when i increase the size it returns zero. 
This is the part of my fragment shader where i'm storing:

```
    uniform layout(binding = 1, rgba32f) writeonly image1D tex1;
    … // more code
    if (flag)
    {
        color = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
            index += (size - i - 1) * i;
        index += a * (size - b - 1) + (i_uv.x + 1) - 1;
        imageStore(tex1, index, vec4(a, b, c, 1.0));
    }
```

and my aplication code is this:

```
imageSize = 0;
int stride{ size - 1 };
for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < size - 1; i++)
    imageSize += (stride - i) * i;

glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 1, &image);
glTextureStorage1D(image, 1, GL_RGBA32F, imageSize);

pixels = new vec4[imageSize];

//Reading back from texture (This part goes outside my game loop)
glBindImageTexture(1, image, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);

shaderFBO.use();
shaderFBO.setUniformi(ShaderType::FRAGMENT_SHADER, 0, size);
shaderFBO.setUniform2v(ShaderType::FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1, vec2(Window::current->getWidth(), Window::current->getHeight()));
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, image);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
std::cout << "\nTexture values\n";
size_t count{ 0 };
for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < imageSize; i++)
{
    if (pixels[i].a != 0)
    {
        std::cout << pixels[i] << std::endl;
        count++;
    }
}
std::cout << count << std::endl;
```

Edit:
I'm gonna put my full vertex and fragment shader, and the application code to help me check if i missed something relevant

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 450 core

out gl_PerVertex
{
vec4 gl_Position;
};

void main()
{
   vec2 p[4] = vec2[4]
   (
    vec2(-1.0, -1.0),
    vec2( 1.0, -1.0),
    vec2(-1.0,  1.0),
    vec2( 1.0,  1.0)
   );

   gl_Position = vec4(p[gl_VertexID], 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 450 core

out vec4 FragColor;

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler1D tex0; // Buffer storing random points
uniform layout(binding = 1, rgba32f) writeonly image1D tex1; // Buffer to store the indices of legal triangles

layout(location = 0) uniform int size;
layout(location = 1) uniform vec2 u_resolution;

vec2 circumcenter(vec2 A, vec2 B, vec2 C, out bool f)
{
vec2 P1 = (A + B) / 2.0;
vec2 P2 = (A + C) / 2.0;

float a1 = -A.x + B.x;
float b1 = A.y - B.y;
float a2 = -A.x + C.x;
float b2 = A.y - C.y;

float c1 = a1*P1.x - b1*P1.y;
float c2 = a2*P2.x - b2*P2.y;

float det = a1*b2 - a2*b1;
vec2 circum = vec2(0.0);
f = false;
if (det != 0)
{
    float x = (b2*c1 - b1*c2) / det;
    float y = (a2*c1 - a1*c2) / det;
    circum = vec2(x, y);
    f = true;
}

return circum;
}

void main()
{
vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
ivec2 i_st = ivec2(floor(st * size));
vec2 f_st = fract(st * size);

vec3 color = vec3(0.0);

if (i_st.y > i_st.x && i_st.y < size - 1)
{
    // Positions of the random points buffer (a, b, c)
    int a = i_st.x;
    int b = i_st.y;
    ivec2 i_uv = ivec2(floor(f_st * (size - b - 1)));
    int c = i_uv.x + b + 1;

    // Points of the triangle
    vec2 A = texelFetch(tex0, a, 0).xy;
    vec2 B = texelFetch(tex0, b, 0).xy;
    vec2 C = texelFetch(tex0, c, 0).xy;

    bool flag;
    vec2 cir = circumcenter(A, B, C, flag);
    if (flag)
    {
        float radius = distance(cir, A);
        // Checking if any other point is inside of the circumscribe circle
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (i == a || i == b || i == c)
                continue;
            vec2 P = texelFetch(tex0, i, 0).xy;
            float dist = distance(cir, P);
            if (dist < radius)
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag)
        {
            color = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // Painting the fargments that correspond to legal triangles
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
                index += (size - i - 1) * i;
            index += a * (size - b - 1) + (i_uv.x + 1) - 1;
            memoryBarrier();
            imageStore(tex1, index, vec4(a, b, c, 1.0)); // Storing indices of legal triangles

        }
    }
}
else 
    color += 1.0;
FragColor = vec4(color, 0.0);
}
```

Application Code:

```
#include "../../Classes/Renderer/Core.h"
#include "../../Classes/Renderer/Shader.h"
#include "../../Classes/Renderer/Input.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

class DT
    : public Core
{
public:
    virtual void Start() override
    {
        srand(time(nullptr));

        shader.addShader("C:/dev/RendererOpenGL/RendererOpenGL/src/Tesis/simpleTri.vert", ShaderType::VERTEX_SHADER);
        shader.addShader("C:/dev/RendererOpenGL/RendererOpenGL/src/Tesis/simpleTri.frag", ShaderType::FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        // Compute Buffer size to store indices of legal triangles
        imageSize = 0;
        int stride{ size - 1 };
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < size - 1; i++)
            imageSize += (stride - i) * i;

        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 1, &image);
        glTextureStorage1D(image, 1, GL_RGBA32F, imageSize);

        pixels = new vec4[imageSize];

        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 1, &texture1D);
        glTextureStorage1D(texture1D, 1, GL_RG32F, size);

        data = new vec2[size];
        // Genereating random points
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < size; i++)
        {
            float x = static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
            float y = static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
            data[i] = vec2(x, y);
            //std::cout << i << ": " << data[i] << std::endl;
        }

        glTextureSubImage1D(texture1D, 0, 0, size, GL_RG, GL_FLOAT, data);
        glBindTextureUnit(0, texture1D);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, texture1D);
        glBindImageTexture(1, image, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);

        // Rendering once to compute legal triangles
        shader.use();
        shader.setUniformi(ShaderType::FRAGMENT_SHADER, 0, size);
        shader.setUniform2v(ShaderType::FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1, vec2(Window::current->getWidth(), Window::current->getHeight()));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        glMemoryBarrier(GL_TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, image);
        glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pixels);


        std::cout << "\nTexture values\n";
        size_t count = 0;
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < imageSize; i++)
        {
            if (pixels[i].a != 0)
            {
                std::cout << pixels[i] << std::endl;
                count++;
            }
        }
        std::cout << count << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void Update() override
    {

    }

    virtual void End() override
    {
        shader.delete_shader();

        glDeleteTextures(1, &texture1D);
        glDeleteTextures(1, &imageSize);

        delete[] data;
        delete[] pixels;
    }

private:
    Shader shader;
    vec2* data;
    const int size{ 20 };

    GLuint texture1D;
    GLuint image;

    size_t imageSize;
    vec4 *pixels;
};

#if 1
CORE_MAIN(DT)
#endif
```

Output:
[The green rectangles are the legal triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSpaS.png) and 
[this is the values retrieved from the 1D texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usUVu.png) . glGetTexImage() doesn't retrieve any data with more than 50 points, and with 30 to 49 i have loss of data but with less than 30 points gives me the correct amount of triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong memory barrier. You have to specify how you intend to use the memory *after* the barrier.

You are using `glGetTexImage` to access the data, so according to the [OpenGL 4.6 Core Profile Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf), Section 7.13 "Shader Memory Access", you have to use (emphasis mine):

> `TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT`: Writes
>   to a texture via `Tex(Sub)Image*`, `ClearTex*Image`, `CopyTex*`, or `CompressedTex*`,
>   **and reads via `GetTexImage`** after the barrier will not execute
>   until all shader writes initiated prior to the barrier complete.

Comment: I've changed to TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT but still don't work.

Comment: I'v solved it, the problem was not only the barrier (thanks @derhass) it was the size of my texture that i created, the max size of the texture1D in my graphics card is of 16384 texels(i think is texels), and i was creating a texture1d greater than 16384